# Should "NUMENÉRA" include the diacritic when written textually?

Tags: discussion

Now that a few more Numenera questions are coming in, there's been some misunderstanding about whether or not there is an accent over the last 'e', which stems from the logo "[NUMENÉRA](http://www.numenera.com/)".

Comment: Sorry - didn't realize I'd created a brand new meta tag.

Comment: Easy enough mistake to make! I reverted my changes to that question and to the [[tag:numenera]] tag wiki based on this. Thanks!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie No problem! I made the meta here, rather just in comments elsewhere, cause I wasn't 100% certain myself after I saw the logo. If anyone sees it anywhere in text, then can bring it up here.

Comment: I did wonder for a moment whether it was simply styling or a name refinement before I did the editing, but I didn't actually... y'know... research it very well. Or at all. So this is useful.

Comment: Changed the title after realizing the slug looked weird... `is-it-numenera-or-numenera`

Answer (score 13):

There is **no accent** over the final 'e' in Numenera. The mark on the logo is **styling**, not an accent.

This is confirmed by the [rest of the website](http://www.numenera.com/overview/) and [Monte Cook's blog](http://www.montecookgames.com/tag/numenera/), where Numenera is written without the accent everywhere in the text, and in the title of the website.

Comment: As a Spanish speaker, I wanted this to be wrong, believing that it could be an issue of US keyboards making it simpler to not carry the accent. But then I went to the core book, and the term is always written without accent.

Comment: As a non-Spanish speaker, I'm curious why? Is it a Spanish-rooted word?

Comment: It's a Latin-rooted word. From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numen : _Numen, pl. numina, ("an influence perceptible by mind but not by senses,is a Latin term for a potential, guiding the course of events in a particular place or in the whole world, used in Roman philosophical and religious thought._

It's just that, in Spanish, we do use accents, and for me, "Numenéra" looked better, even though it'd actually be incorrect Spanish: accents are not written on the penultimate syllable of a word when the word ends in a vowel. But it still looked nicer :)

Comment: I thought it was more of a pun on “new men era”.

Answer (score 7):

## What do Official Sources Say?

For:

- [Someone working on the Numenera vidoe game seems to think it's a diacritic](https://torment.uservoice.com/forums/197950-game-ideas/suggestions/3793821-french-typo-about-the-name-of-the-game-).

Against:

- I couldn't find a single instance of a diacritic on the site, [including the "What in a Name" page](http://www.numenera.com/setting/whats-in-a-name-numenera/), which is literally all about the name of the game.
- There's no accent in the book text itself, [even when it's writing the logo it out in smallcaps with a trademark sign](http://i40.photobucket.com/albums/e235/dan_martland/cf9f0f2dc43506be56f6076f4c4b3ef3_zpsa598f8f7.jpg).

**My conclusion is that it doesn't actually have a diacritic.**

Comment: +1 for the nice find, tho I would argue that the rep for the video game is mistaken on their reasoning.

Comment: @dlras2 I'm inclined to agree. Still, it's a data point.

Answer (score 3):

Oddly enough, the stylistic accent on the *e* seems to be inaccurate in terms of the word’s origin.

As @AdrianoVaroliPiazza points out in a comment,

> It's a Latin-rooted word. From en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numen : *Numen, pl. numina, ("an influence perceptible by mind but not by senses,is a Latin term for a potential, guiding the course of events in a particular place or in the whole world, used in Roman philosophical and religious thought.* It's just that, in Spanish, we do use accents, and for me, "Numenéra" looked better, even though it'd actually be incorrect Spanish: accents are not written on the penultimate syllable of a word when the word ends in a vowel. But it still looked nicer :)

He’s mostly correct, but *numenera* is not a Latin word. The word *numen* is, but it’s also a Spanish word (with the same forms, s. *numen* pr. "numEn", and pl. *numina* pr. "numIna"), and Latin does not have the *-era* suffix while [Spanish does](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-era#Spanish): it implies the place or object where the suffixed noun is usually found. This suffix is explicitly *-era* not *-éra*, so *numenéra* would be incorrect as Adriano points out. The word would still be pronounced "numenEra" in Spanish, though.

That said, I think the correct form would be *numinera* rather than *numenera*, but either way *numenéra* is right out.

For those curious, by my estimation, the meaning of the word would probably be something close to a shrine: it’s a *place where one finds a guiding spirit* or perhaps an *object containing a guiding spirit*, or possibly *the state of being a such a spirit* (“*spirit-ness*”).

Comment: @AdrianoVaroliPiazza I’d love for you to confirm or correct my Spanish; this started as just me talking about Latin but I delved a bit into the Spanish even though I do not know the language.

Comment: Given how language changes, it's to be expected that it would mutate over the course of eight civilisations. What's surprising is that it's recognisable as a Latin-rooted word at all. Or maybe that's just artistic license for the convenience of an English-language RPG. ;)

Comment: As to the origin, Monte's [written about it in his design diaries](http://www.numenera.com/whats-in-a-name-numenera/). The reason I didn't quote it in my answer is it's a year old, and possibly outdated if he decided to stylistically add an accent on.

Comment: Some extra quips: I said "it's a Latin-rooted" word", not "it's a Latin word" :). As for the time passed while still sounding Latin, it could be a _cognate_ (it sounds Latin, but only by chance).

Comment: Something I didn't correct: though numenera follows grammatical and orthographical rules of the Spanish language, it is not a Spanish word: it's neither accepted by the Real Academia Española de la Lengua (the official body that reviews and "controls" the language), nor in common use in any Spanish-speaking country. Could be a neologism, in a few years :)

Comment: @AdrianoVaroliPiazza Thanks! And yes, I realized it was not a proper, recognized Spanish word; I actually specifically avoided saying that it was. I said it wasn't a Latin word, and pointed out the *-era* construction in Spanish, which Latin works. My intent was something along the lines of "*numenera* **could not** be a Latin work, but could be a Spanish word (though it isn’t)."